# how to Monitoring multiple mysql using prometheus with grafana?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

Monitoring MySQL Server Using Prometheus, Grafana, and mysqld_exporter 
in  Grafana I use " Mysql - Prometheus" Dashboard.

Prometheus has two mysql-explorer  Targets.
and in Grafana had "Multiple Series Error" at top of   "instance up " panel.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? am currently in the same dilemma

Answer (score 0):

Normally you at least need to modify queries for variables in the dashboard depends on your environment.

If you share your scrape job config and Grafan dashboard id or link, I might be able to help you.